# Bucketize data points and find availability - promql

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql

I have a metric data coming in as a inc counter.
1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,9

So when there is an increment it means a healthy service.
I need to find out in a 5 minute rolling window if there were no increment at all. So something like -
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1.(1 can be any non zero float) Then get a cumulative sum as 2(unhealthy) 14(healthy)
and find a % on these numbers.

I tried increase in promql and fiddled around it but could not make it work.

```
SUM(increase(metricA{status='healthy'}[10m])==0)
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The following promql query triggers when there were no increments for the given `metricA` during the last 5 minutes:

```
changes(metricA[5m]) == 0
```

This query uses [changes()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#changes) function for calculating the number of [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) changes (aka increases) on the given lookbehind window in square brackets.

If you need calculating the percentage of service availability during the given lookbehind window, then the following query can be used:

```
100 * changes(metricA[5m])
  /
count_over_time(metricA[5m])
```

See [count_over_time() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_over_time).